# Property of nowhere flat functions

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Suppose $ f(\cdot) $ is a real valued function on $ [0, 1] $ with the following property. For each $ x \in [0, 1] $, there exists an integer $ k_x $ such that $ f^{(k_x)}(\cdot) $ exists and is nonzero at $ x $. I am wondering if $ k_x $ can be uniformly bounded for all $ x $ or if a counterexample can be constructed. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What if $f$ is not differentiable?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my question.